# How to mock a call to a method of a related model?

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following django models

```
class Charge(models.Model):
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def execute():
        # make some external calls
        return invoice_url

class Transaction(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    charge = models.ForeignKey(Charge)

    def do_charge():
        self.charge = Charge.objects.create(total=self.product.price)
        url = self.charge.execute()
        return url
```

I'm trying to test `do_charge` by mocking the call to `execute`. 
The problem is that the object is being created within `do_charge`.

Something like that (this is obviously not working just to illustrate)

```
@mock.patch('Charge.execute')
def test_should_return_url(self, mock):
    mock.side_effect = 'www.foo.testing/invoice' 
    t = Transaction.objects.create(product=p1)
    invoice_url = t.do_charge()
    self.assertIsEqual(invoice_url, 'www.foo.testing/invoice')
```

Is it possible to mock `Charge.execute`?

python 3.4, django 1.8.

Comment: Execute is not a staticmethod, is it?

Comment: No, it's an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried next code to test mock behavior and it seems that mocking Charge.execute should work.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         return 'a'

>>> @mock.patch('__main__.A.foo', return_value='12')
... def bar(mockfoo):
...     a = A()
...     return a.foo()
... 
>>> bar()
'12'
```

Here I've mocked a method of the class, make a class instance and called object's method and it used mocked version. So I think in your test mocked Charge.execute will be used. I think the problem you are facing can be related with correct path to the class you want to mock.

Comment: Yeh, the problem is that when assigning the mocked `charge` to `transaction.charge` it throws for invalid type (which makes sense). Though it might be possible to mock only the model instance method.